# Django rest framework: Cascade activate/deactivate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am working on an API using django and django rest framework, what I want to do is cascading with two action for related models

1. Deleting an instance and that goes smothely with no problem using on_delete=modles.CASCADE on the models.ForeignKey.
2. Activation and deactivation and here is the problem

Each model I defined in my application there is a boolean field is_*active which indicates if this instance is active or not, what I want to do here is to cascade activation and deactivation whenever the is*_active field changes and I want to handle this in a dynamic way because my application is growing big and I don't want to change this service manually every time I create a new foreign key for any model.

For example I have the following models

```
class Company(AbstractNamingModel):
   
    name_en = models.CharField(_("English Name"), max_length=64, unique=True, null=True,    blank=True)
    name_ar = models.CharField(_("Arabic Name"), max_length=64, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("Is Active"),
        blank=True,
        default=True,
    )

class Branch(AbstractNamingModel):
    
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=("Company branches"),
        related_name="company_branches",
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_("Is Active"), blank=True, default=True)

class Department(AbstractNamingModel):

    branch = models.ForeignKey(
        Branch,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Branch Departments",
        related_name="branch_departments",
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("Is Active"),
        blank=True,
        default=True,
    )
class Employee(AbstractUser, TimeStampedModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name_en = models.CharField(_("English Name"), max_length=100)
    name_ar = models.CharField(_("Arabic Name"), max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="employees",
    )

    branch = models.ForeignKey(
        Branch,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="employees",
    )
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="employees",
    )
```

what I want to do is when I activate/deactivate a company I cascade the action to activate/deactivate all branches, departments, employees and any other model instances that a company, branch, department or employee is related to this company same thing should happen with branches, department, employees and all models in my system.
How can this be handled dynamically the same way on_delete models.CASCADE works?

I tried to use the the apps.get_models() method but this gave me all the models in the application and I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to think about your problem in a different way, all of your models *share* one piece of data `is_active=True or False`.

This shared piece of data should be in its own table with an FK to each of the records (for simplicity sake). Then, when setting inactive, each model can reference it e.g.

```py
class Status(Model): # naming is hard
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```py
company.status.is_active = False
company.status.is_active.save()

assert branch.status.is_active == False
```

Something like this would allow you to maintain `is_active` (and anything else you want to share between all entities) in one source for each company